# Auto data input from lists in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 3 colums of data (vehicle name, vehicle registration, vehicle number) Specifically column O,P,Q

I want excel to automatically put in the correct data for vehicle registration and vehicle number into cell B &C when i select a vehicle name from a list in cell A. The list pulls its data from column O.

I can build a list using data validation but how do i tell excel that for example "when vehicle Daisy is clicked put in Daisy's corresponding registration and number into the adjacent cells"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your linked file, put this in cell C4 to look up the vehicle name in E4 from the list in O3 to Q75 and return the ID, which is in the third column

```
=VLOOKUP($E4,$O$3:$Q$75,3,FALSE)
```

To return the Registration, use the second column.

```
=VLOOKUP($E4,$O$3:$Q$75,2,FALSE)
```

If you nest the Vlookup in an IfError or another function, you don't need to start it with a = sign. The = sign is only required at the start of the formula.

```
=iferror(VLOOKUP($E4,$O$3:$Q$75,3,FALSE),"Not found")
```

Comment: Ok that's working correctly across cells C4, D4 & E5 (where i need it to work) however when i paste in the same formulas into C7, D7 & E7 because i have multiple vehicles that will be on this sheet it duplicates the data from C4 and D4 into C7 and D7

Comment: Take note of the $ signs. They are important. In row 4 the formula will look at E4 `=VLOOKUP($E4,$O$3:$Q$75,3,FALSE)`. Copy the cell and paste it down. Then in row 7 it will be `=VLOOKUP($E7,$O$3:$Q$75,3,FALSE)`, so it will look at E7 and return the data for the vehicle in E7. If your result is different, check that you have applied the formula correctly.

Comment: Stupid mistake on my behalf. That's working perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of completing the info after selecting the vehicle name, is probably to fill B&C with a `VLOOKUP`.
*Syntax 
`=VLOOKUP (value, table, col_index, [range_lookup])`*

A simple `=VLOOKUP(A1,O:Q,2,FALSE)` for `B1`
and `=VLOOKUP(A1,O:Q,3,FALSE)` for `C1` should work.
Where `A1` is the position of the list.

You can just fill them down if you have multiple lists.

The problem with this would be that if nothing is chosen, the cells would display `#N/A`
But this is solved with a `IFERROR` like so:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,O:Q,2,FALSE),"")
```

[image]

Further explanation of the function.

```
Syntax 
=VLOOKUP (value, table, col_index, [range_lookup])
Arguments 
value - The value to look for in the first column of a table.
table - The table from which to retrieve a value.
col_index - The column in the table from which to retrieve a value.
range_lookup - [optional] TRUE = approximate match (default). FALSE = exact match.
```

So we are saying "Take the value in A1, then in columns O to Q look for that value. When that value is found, return the value in the second (or third for C) column"
Good luck!

Comment: If i uploaded a excel file would you be able to make an example for me? I've never worked with VLOOKUP before so i haven't got the foggiest what i'm doing.

Comment: I could, but you literally just have to add that function like it's written to the cells. Since you figured out how to do a list, this should be easy. Just copy this: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("A"&ROW());$O:$Q;2;FALSE);"")` and paste it in the cell right next to your list.

Comment: Its not working for me. Its telling me that when excel sees an "=" sign it thinks its a formula.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/881304/template.xlsm

Comment: @ChristoferWeber What's the purpose of Indirect() when the only variable is Row()? Why not just use a relative reference?

Comment: @Exhausted But it is a formula. It's supposed to be. In that example, the list isn't in A, so the function doesn't work right out of the box. In `C4` you'd want `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E4,$O:$Q,2,FALSE),"")` and in `D4` `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E4,$O:$Q,3,FALSE),""`

Comment: @teylyn If his list was on A2 instead of A1, and he pasted it next to it (so in B2), how else would I make sure that it's pointing at the list?

Comment: @Exhausted https://www.dropbox.com/s/2iidldjie23od4r/template.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: @ChristoferWeber Well certainly not with the highly inefficient and volatile INDIRECT(). Instead use `A1` and tell them to adjust the row as required.

Comment: @teylyn Well I did that first, that's in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Formula:

- In cell B=index(O2:Q3,match(a2,O2:03,0)2)
- In cell C=index(O2:Q3,match(a2,O2:03,0)3)
- Your data is in col. O (NAMES), P (REG) Q (NUMBER)

A2 is the validation list cell, match will take this and find its location as Row in Index formula and find the column 2 for Reg, and 3 for Number.

This is faster than VLOOKUP